# Screen tearing when creating window with parameter glfwGetPrimaryMonitor()

Tags: opengl, graphics, glfw

```
    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(1920, 1080, "test", NULL, NULL);
```

Creating Window like this results in a smooth rendering with 60 fps when moving camera, but It is not occupying full screen.

```
    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(1920, 1080, "test", glfwGetPrimariMonitor(), NULL);
```

Creating Window like this results in a screen tearing(720 fps) when moving camera, but occupying the full screen.

1. I have a high-end pc.
2. `glfwSwapInterval(1);` vSync enabled.
3. Also tried `wglSwapIntervalEXT(1);`

This problem occurs on every program (rendering a basic triangle to complex shadow mapping) and on my both pc.
I want to render on full screen without screen tearing. Any solution?

Comment: Do you use double buffering ([`glfwWindowHint( GLFW_DOUBLEBUFFER, GLFW_TRUE)`](http://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/window_guide.html#window_hints_fb))?

Comment: @Rabbid76 no, never used this.

Comment: Doesn't matter, `GLFW_DOUBLEBUFFER` is by default `GLFW_TRUE`. See [Supported and default values](http://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/window_guide.html#window_hints_values)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enabling verticle sync option in Nvidia control panel solved this issue.